# DAX looking up value in another table based on measure being between 2 columns in the look up table

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a tabular model in which we calculate a score for a metric. The performance score is measure in the model. Result set of the query is something like this:

`MetricID|PerformanceScore
   1          50
   2          30`

Based on the score we assign points based on which range the performance score falls into. The score table looks like this:

`Metric|LowRange|HighRange|Points
   1      0         60       1
   1      60        100      2
   2      0         15       1
   2      15        100      2`

I want to be able to add a measure into the model which would allow us to return this:

`MetricID|PerformanceScore|Points
   1          50             1
   2          30             2`

What would be the to create this measure?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your tables are named `Performance` and `Ranges` and have a relationship on the columns `MetricID = Metric`.

You should be able to create a calculated column that pulls in the appropriate `Points` value on the first table, `Performace` as follows:

```
Points = MAXX(
             FILTER(RELATEDTABLE(Ranges),
                 Ranges[LowRange] <= Performance[PerformanceScore] &&
                 Ranges[HighRange] > Performance[PerformanceScore]),
             Ranges[Points])
```

If you want to do this as a measure, try this:

```
PointsMeasure = MAXX(
                    FILTER(RELATEDTABLE(Ranges),
                        Ranges[LowRange] <= MAX(Performance[PerformanceScore]) &&
                        Ranges[HighRange] > MAX(Performance[PerformanceScore])),
                    Ranges[Points])
```

I like using a variable to make it more readable:

```
PointsMeasure =
    VAR Score = MAX(Performance[PerformanceScore])
    RETURN MAXX(
               FILTER(RELATEDTABLE(Ranges),
                   Ranges[LowRange] <= Score &&
                   Ranges[HighRange] > Score),
               Ranges[Points])
```